# Seeding spatial fields with Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, geo

I'm using Laravel (5.5) Lumen, PHP 7.2, MySQL 5.7, and I have a field in a table that's using a MySQL point spatial field type. It's created correctly, but I can't figure out how to populate it from a `Seeder`.

The field is created in a migration declared like this:

```
$table->point('location')->spatialIndex();
```

Where `$table` is a `Blueprint`.

Then I try to seed it like this:

```
DB::table('locations')->insert(
    [
        'location' => "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(140.7484404 -73.9878441)')"
    ]
);
```

or:

```
'location' => 'POINT(140.7484404 -73.9878441)'
```

I also tried this, since I've added the `grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial` package:

```
'location' => new Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point(140.7484404, -73.9878441)
```

But all of these give some variation on:

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: check this out https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/issues/17

Comment: I don't see how that would solve this - I'm not using Builder. Blueprint has support for spatial fields anyway, so this should be possible without using that package - I was just interested in it for further enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been over two years, I solved a similar problem with `point` using `DB::raw` like this:

```php
'location' => \DB::raw('POINT(140.7484404 -73.9878441)')
```

Without `DB::raw`, the `POINT(x,y)` part of the `INSERT` query is wrapped inside `'`.

More info about `DB::raw` here in [lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/database)/[laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database) docs.